# How to animate the barplots in a bar graph using Core Plot in iOS

Tags: ios, object, core-plot

As I am trying to animate a vertical bar graph like:

1. At first we can see only one plot on the graph and the next coming plot is half visible( and I done this with barOffset and setting the range of the x.axis as 2.
2. When I left swipe on to the graph the second plot should take place of first one and third to second like wise.

   - For this I taken a transparent view on top of the graph and applied handled the swipe and applied transform like animation the plots by using timer where I am increasing the range value by 0.2 ... 0.2 ... 0.2 ... till next plot range so it seems like transform animation.
   - The problem here is when I swipe left the first plot moves left and the second plot comes on to the screen. My need is the first plot should stay there itself until the second plot occupies its place.

Guys, please help me with your ideas since I am new to Coreplot.

Thanks,
Monish